# dynamic router-links on vue.js not working

Tags: routes, vue.js

I'm pulling the last strand of my hair. What am I missing please?

Each link is displayed correctly on the address bar when clicked, but the page is not loaded or routed. Refreshing thereafter shows the correct page.

[routes]
`

```
import eachPost from './components/eachPost.vue';
{ path: '/eachPost/:id', component: eachPost }
```

[component]

```
<router-link :to="'/eachPost/' + post.p_id" v-for="(post,i) in posts" 
:key="i" exact>{{ post.header }}</router-link>
```

`

the list of router-links is displayed on every component including eachPost.vue iself. The page is routed only when clicked from other components but not from the eachPost.vue component.

Comment: Are you saying that the page does not refresh when you are on the eachPost page and click the eachPost link? That's expected behaviour.

Comment: No, not on the same link. From other components, all the rourter-links work. but once I'm on say link1 (by this point, I would be in eachPost.vue component), when i click any of the router-links, they do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your problem. You need to watch the route for changes in the param (not one of Vue's most intuitive features, I know!). So, in your base component you need to do:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // Whatever you need to change route
  } 
}
```

The thing here is that the component does not get re-rendered, so if you are fetching data when you create the element, that same method needs to be called when the route changes. Here's a basic example:

```
{
  template: '<div>{{message}}</div>',
  created() {
    this.setMessage();
  },
  methods:{
    setMessage(){
      this.message = 'Bar ' + this.$route.params.id;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      this.setMessage();
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  }
}
```

All I'm doing here is changing the message when the route changes, you can see this in action on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unrm8tcL/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see what I'm missing now. Works like magic! Voted.

Comment: Excellent,you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

If you use a dynamic route, the same component will be reused.

Here is a reference to add to craig_h's answer:
https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

look at the section **Reacting to Params Changes**

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.
>
> To react to params changes in the same component, you can simply watch the $route object:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Voted.